# Atualizar datatable quando realizar busca pelo autocomplete

Tags: java, ajax, java-ee, primefaces

Bom dia pessoal.. Alguém poderia tirar uma dúvida? Bom é o seguinte, eu tenho um componente do primefaces autocomplete e um datatable, porém quando eu realizo uma busca pelo autocomplete, ele não atualiza meu datatable, como faço isso?

Abaixo segue meu autocomplete e meu datatable:

```
<p:autoComplete id="station_select"
   value="#{pmvBean.pmv}"
   completeMethod="#{pmvBean.completePmv}"
   var="pmv" itemValue="#{pmv}"
   itemLabel="#{pmv.location}"
   converter="pmvConverter"
   styleClass="autoComplete-1"
   placeholder="#{bundle['system.msg.history.selectPmv']}" 
   dropdown="true" 
   scrollHeight="500">

</p:autoComplete>

<p:dataTable id="pmv_datatable" value="#{pmvBean.listPmv}"
    widgetVar="pmvDatatable" var="pmv" rowKey="#{pmv.id}"
    sortBy="#{pmv.location}"
    emptyMessage="#{bundle['system.ui.label.emptyDataTable']}"
    style="margin-top: 10px;">
```

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa utilizar um ajax para atualizar a dataTable e criar um método no seu Bean para tratar o evento:

```
<p:autoComplete ...atributos...>
  <f:ajax event="itemSelect" 
    listener="#{pmvBean.listenerParaEsseEvento}" render="pmv_dataTable" />
</p:autoComplete>
```